# Dimension analysis of one dimensional wave equation

Tags: wave-equation, dimensional-analysis

$$\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \space \nabla^2 u$$
$u(x,t)$ is the amplitude of the wave at position $x$ and time $t$. I want to show by dimension analysis that $c$ has to be of the dimension velocity.

**My thoughts:**

Wave amplitude $u$ is of dimension length, L.

Position $x$ is of dimension length, L.

Time $t$ is of dimension time, T.

$c^2\nabla ^2u=c^2\nabla \cdot \nabla u=c^2\nabla\cdot[\frac {\partial u}{\partial x},\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}]=c^2(\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2})  $

Substituting the variables with their corresponding unit yields
$$L/T^2=[c]^2((L/L^2)+(L/T^2))=[c]^2((1/L)+(L/T^2))$$ $[c]$ means dimension of $c$. Given that I know that $c$ is of dimension velocity, L/T.
$$(L^2/T^2)((1/L)+(L/T^2))=L/T^2+L^3/T^4$$
Which makes no sense.

Comment: $c^2\nabla \cdot \nabla u=c^2\nabla\cdot[\frac {\partial u}{\partial x},\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}]$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla^2$ is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$, with no partial w/r to time.  Thus:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}  &=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\, ,\\
&= \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial (ct)^2}
\end{align}
so that $ct$ must have the same dimensions as $x$.  The correct dimensionality of $c$ follows immediately.